# Create index across multiple Mongodb collections in parallel

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have lots of collections which all have same fields that I'd like to index on. I can perform the sequential index by using:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('mydb');
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collectionName) {
    db.collectionName.createIndex( { orderDate: 1, zipcode: -1 } )
});
```

I would like to know if it's possible to create index in parallel with similar script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index builds are not sequential internally, in any database. There are two cases you can consider:

1. Your collection is empty. In this case, no data needs to be indexed. So the `createIndex` command just has to create an index definition for future purposes (write operations).
2. Your collection is populated. In this case, the index definition will be created and the indexing process will start in the background, and when all of the data in the collection is indexed, only then the index will be marked as ready for use.

So even, if you are calling `createIndex`, iteratively here:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('mydb');
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collectionName) {
    db.collectionName.createIndex( { orderDate: 1, zipcode: -1 } )
});
```

The process of populating the data in the index is done in the background. So, if you trigger multiple such commands, their data will be populated parallelly in the background.

Read more about index builds [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-creation/#std-label-index-operations).
[Create Index MongoDB.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

Answer (score 0):

In the mongosh shell, you can use the same concept to create indexes across multiple collections in parallel.

---

Here's an example of how to create index in multiple collection:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('dbName');
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collectionName) {
db.getCollection(collectionName).createIndex({employee_name : 1, joining_date : -1}) 
});
```

Make sure to replace **'dbName'** with your actual database nam, and adjust the index object as needed for your specific index requirements.